# VirtualBox is turning off after BSOD in a guest system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Windows XP in VMWare VirtualBox 6.1.14 r140239. I made a guest system crash with a BSOD, but the VM just closed and turned off, even though HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\AutoReboot is set to 1 (enabled). How do i make a VM reboot after crash?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is it the VM that won't start, or Virtual Box itself? VirtualBox is the hypervisor software running on the host system. The VM is distinct from it but dependent on it. Please edit your post and it's title to make it more specific and clear.

Comment: If it is the Guest that is crashing (it seems so but is not clear), try to start the Guest with the Windows XP CD and see if you can repair it.